# How can I propose new rules for posting on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I have collected more things that can be improved or that cause confusion + frustration for a lot of users and would like to be able to propose some new rules with the ability to confront directly with complete arguments the "opinion" leaders and the rule makers.

Also I am asking this because until now there are, at least in my opinion, some requests that were rejected or left without big attention because of the author's lack of maybe more strong and convincing arguments.

Specifically I ask if there is kind of form/template to complete which would be analysed more focused, rather then leaving it as a question for community's "pop corn" sake.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments since the question has been substantially edited.

Comment: Given that this appears to be about Stack Overflow, why isn't this being asked (or migrated to) Meta.Stack Overflow? I am also curious if these ***rules*** are community social norms that may differ from community to community (shog may say things, and that may or may not change how people use the software), or hard coded thingies that are handed down from on high about how the software actually works? And yes, these are sometimes hard to separate.

Comment: All of my what.

Comment: For those who may care) until now this post received around +20 upvotes))) just that the downvotes are more).. but you can't know that there are upvotes right?) because the sum is negative).. seems  ironic for my "wrong" understanding of the "voting" system on SO and it's aims and values)

Comment: @Fawkes with sufficient reputation, one can ***easily*** see that the score is +4/-12 at the time I write this. I am really still wondering what your actual question is and if you are trying to change social norms, the software, or a mixture of the two. And yes, I read revision 1 - it is clear that you haven't taken time to read the background material from other related questions in the past.

Comment: @MichaelT, do you really start looking for the pluses and minuses or you just usually look for the total(which is the only available at first sight)? And that is a simple UX problem, no more than that. I understand that you really wanna prove who is wrong here, even though I was just trying to understand what mechanisms for changing something on this platform, exist. And then maybe use them for the issues I have.

Comment: @Fawkes I can assure you that on sites where I [have the reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), I frequently look at what the score break down is. I believe that understanding how votes are cast is important in understanding the direction the community is taking on the post which is important for consideration in moderating the site as a non-diamond. The *reason* why it is restricted is that its a fairly heavy toll on the database (fetch from votes table) compared to the display of the score (in the posts table).

Comment: @MichaelT So.. I'm using a product and because of some shown information in some hidden way, I really get it wrong and in the end decide to use a wrong solution and in this way create problems for myself (the usual UX discussions). Do you really think I care what is happening with the db somewhere there? Does it help me in the  "why I access this site"? Definitely not. But we are already getting very far away. Do you have some constructive/objective suggestion which you think should be added to the final solution ?  If not, we can have [arguing fun] in a private chat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any proposed changes have to be looked over by the community as well as Stack Overflow the Company. This is what meta is here for. Make a post tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), present your case, and see how things go from there.

The trick is to make sure you have a thorough proposal that includes a clear problem statement (what issue are you trying to address?), considers the pros, the cons, past history of discussions (if any), and does all that without an overall air of "everything about how things work right now is the actual worst". Your idea might still not be supported, but you'd at least cut down on the "popcorn" factor.

You may also find [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) helpful.

Comment: Also related/helpful: [Shog's answer to "Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/603977)